# Joomla : Could not instantiate mail function

Tags: joomla

I have developed a website in joomla, and I have a contact us page, in that the form works fine only when I use to send an email from the same domain

Eg :

From : rimaz@abcd.com 
To   : john@abcd.com

But when I send to a different domain the form gives an error as "Could not instantiate mail function."

Eg :

From : rimaz@abcd.com 
To   : john@gmail.com

Can anyone explain me about this problem ??

Comment: Do you have mail enabled on your server and in php.ini?

Comment: You need to provide more details, like is it Joomla!'s built-in contact form, how have you set up mail in Joomla!'s Global Preferences... what version of Joomla! are you using... when exactly does the error occur.

Comment: @K2xL I am using yahoo as my hosting plan, how can I edit php.ini in yahoo

Comment: @cppl I tried with several contact forms and Joomla's built in form,  and my Joomla Version is 1.5. I tried many options but nothing works for me.

Comment: @iShader Ok, but how have you set up mail in Joomla!'s Global Preferences and when exactly does the error occur or is it silent ? (By the way you should update your question with these details most people will skip the comments).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of debugging your providers SMTP / email setup you can use the new mandrill service from the guys who do mailchimp - Mandrill ( http://blog.mailchimp.com/public-beta-of-mandrill-smtp-email-service/ ) with the plugin :

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/mailing-a-distribution-lists/20624

> Mandrill is a plugin that allows your Joomla installation to send transactional emails. The only thing you need to do is to provide your Mandrill API key and enable the plugin. After that all emails (new user registration, password reset etc) will be send through the Mandrill service.
>
> Mandrill Features:
>
> - Uses MailChimp's awesome email delivery engine instead of your server
> - Tracks opens and clicks so you know how effective these emails are to your users . Now you can > see what you need to change to make them
>     more effective.
> - Has pretty, visual reports of the email results
> - Allows you to tag the emails and see your stats filtered by tag
>
> Why would understanding transactional emails be important for you. An example is when a user signs > up on your site an email is sent via Joomla. But, you get no reports to understand how effective that email did. These emails are sent as instructions to your users telling them a message you want them to understand. Where they designed good? Was the content well written? Was it structured properly? This is hard to say when it goes thru Joomla but now you will understand all this when the emails goes thru Mandrill.

Answer (score 0):

This is a setting from your host. YOu can ask them for help in figuring out how to make it work, but they are trying to prevent you from using their hosting to spam people.
Sometimes it is possible to work around it but not always.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens due to restrictive mail server settings, which you most likely don't have influence on with shared hosting.

If you have more control over the server, you should fix the mail server settings.

If not, the easiest way is to use Joomla's ability to send mails using any SMTP mail account. Create a mail account for Joomla, and enter the credentials in Joomla's configuration. Joomla will then use that account to send mails. So will extensions, if they are properly written.